# How can I avoid relative paths in #includes when building with Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm struggling to understand the logic of how `includes` work in Bazel targets. I want my code to be modular, so I am trying to avoid `#include` statements with relative or long absolute paths.

Suppose I have the following workspace structure:

```
tree .                                                                                  
. 
├── BUILD
├── is_binary_tree
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── is_binary_tree.cpp
├── lib
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── graphs.cpp
│   └── graphs.h
└── WORKSPACE
```

I'm getting the following warning when trying to `bazel build //is_binary_tree:is_binary_tree` and I don't understand what it means :

> WARNING: /is_binary_tree/BUILD:1:10:
> in includes attribute of cc_binary rule
> //is_binary_tree:is_binary_tree: '../lib' resolves to 'lib' not below
> the relative path of its package 'is_binary_tree'. This will be an
> error in the future

Why would `../lib` *resolve* to `lib`. Lib should be in the parent directory of is_binary_tree, so from the standpoint of is_binary_tree it can be found at ../lib, isn't this right?

To get rid of the relative path and avoid having something like  `#include ../lib/graphs.h` in `is_binary_tree/is_binary_tree.cpp` I added an *includes* attribute to my `is_binary_tree` target like so:

**is_binary_tree/is_binary_tree.cpp**

```
#include "graphs.h"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

**is_binary_tree/BUILD**

```
cc_binary(
    name="is_binary_tree",
    srcs=["is_binary_tree.cpp"],
    includes=["../lib"],
    deps=["//lib:graphs"],
)
```

And I'm getting the aforementioned WARNING. What am I missing?

And more broadly, what is the best way to include dependencies without having long relative paths in #include statements ? (I want my code to be modular and not specific to a given Bazel workspace folder organization)

Thanks

Comment: If Bazel is like make and other tools, you do not put the paths in the include statements, just the file names.  The tool has a list of paths to search for include files.

Comment: It is exactly what I am trying to do, but I am confused about the warning I am getting.

Comment: Since you've made lib:graphs a dep, you just need graph.h to be in hdrs.  https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_import.hdrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `includes` should go in `//lib:graphs`, so that anything which depends on it (has it in `deps`) uses it. `lib/BUILD` should look like this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "graphs",
    hdrs = ["graphs.h"],
    srcs = ["graphs.cpp"],
    includes = ["."],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Then you drop `includes` from `is_binary_tree` and it should work.

In general, each Bazel target contains information about its files. It depends on other targets to use their files.

More broadly, Bazel defaults to #include paths relative to the base of the [repository](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/build-ref.html#repositories). That means you'd write `#include "lib/graphs.h"` in any file, whether that's `is_binary_tree/is_binary_tree.cpp` or `x/y/z/foobar.cpp`. That avoids collisions between `graphics/constants.h` and `audio/constants.h`, without using absolute paths.